# Haskell create list with map and apply division

Tags: haskell

I'm supposed to use the **map** function to create a list and **divide it by 2** to calculate the average, but I'm stuck at the division part.

```
mittelWert (n,m) = map (+n) [m]
```

This gives me my list, but i cant divide it by 2 now...

I tried this:

```
mittelWert (n,m) = map (+n) [m] / 2
```

and this:

```
mittelWert (n,m) = map (+n) [m] `div` 2
```

ty.

error: `* Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Fractional [b]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    * When checking the inferred type`

Comment: Well how would you divide a list by two? Furthermore the question does not makes much sense. Why should you divide the element by two to calculate the average? Here you create a list with one element, which is weird since using the item itself is easier.

Comment: ok, that makes i cant divide list  just by a element. then maybe a second map function which divides the result of the first by 2?.. Edit: mittelWert (n,m) = map (/2) (map (+n) [m]) works!! ty :D

Comment: you can also alter the first map. But right now it does not makes (any) sense to use a list to start with. If you want to calculate the average of two numbers `n` and `m`, you can define it as `(m+n)/2` (or `div (m+n) 2` for integers).

Comment: i know, but the the task is asked like this, im supposed to use map to get the average :P

Comment: the average of a list is a number, but the result of a map - any map - is a list.

Comment: I strongly encourage you to check with your teacher (or a TA) to make sure that you have understood the exercise. This is not a sensible way to write code, and I do not believe that your teacher is intending to set an exercise whose only solution is not sensible.

Answer (score 0):

```
mittelWert (n,m) = map (/2) (map (+n) [m])
```

two map functions did the job. **one gets the sum into a list** and then divides the list by a **second map function by 2**

Comment: I guess you try to do `\n m -> sum . map (/2) $ n:[m]`

Comment: what are you doing? how this is different from `(m+n) \`div\` 2`?